# Entity Framework vs Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am only starting with Entity Framework and I appreciate the direct mapping of code to the tables in my database. What I do not see just yet is the practicality of having to use EF over stored procedures and I would appreciate anyone's opinion about this. I am not being lazy and I am searching this myself at the moment. Thought I can post the question and hear from others as well.

My case is EF being an ORM is most suited to mapping in the tables in my database. But in a live web server many requests can happen at one time that may be taxing the database in having to compile the text queries prior to executing them compared to just simply executing stored procedure which are pre-compiled already. EF can also map to SPs but I feel that this is somewhat diminishing the value of ORM.

I would really appreciate an eye-opener in this case.

Comment: Then as a programmer wouldn't you rather not have to maintain 100's of stored procs. Add a column to your domain object and bam all your queries are updated. With stored procs you have to manually edit each and every one. ORM's solve 95% of your querying, the other 5% can be stored procs.

Comment: Phil, I agree and that you are right from a programmers perspective. In our office though we have a DB team who does all the database definitions from the ground up. That would include all the tables, indexes, SPs, etc. They also do some policies where certain users can only access certain SPs. Switching to EF is like me doing the stuffs that they are already doing. :(

Comment: Ouch, we have a DBA, he maintains everything with the DB except the queries, we use NHibernate here, but we have a mix of about 2000 Stored Procs + NH Queries. We are slowly moving all our Stored Procs to NH simply because it's far too hard to main them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because EF isn't using sprocs, it doesn't mean that the parameterised queries it runs won't get compiled and cached. SQL Server has got a lot more clever about that over the years.

Comment: That is True; SQL Server will cache adhoc query plans; but when it gets it wrong, it does so at the expense of data pages...:(

Comment: Yes I know this is an old post. But in searching on this topic I ran by this post and it always helps to have more information. So I just wanted to throw this out there as an interesting read on the subject:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2003/11/18/38178.aspx

which states that all ad-hoc queries (which EF queries are) are cached since SQL 2000.

And this:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/21/sql-server-2008-optimize-for-ad-hoc-workloads-advance-performance-optimization/

Which shows how 2008 can optimize and query over the cached queries tables.

Answer (score 3):

You might find Jeff's commentary on the subject helpful: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/stored-procedures-vs-ad-hoc-sql.html.

His point is basically that stored procedure's can be seen as a kind of premature optimization, and you really should make sure this is the performance bottleneck in your application before going that route.  For instance, there are frameworks available to mock up 1000's of simultaneous web requests to see how your database will *really* perform under load in one situation versus the other.

Comment: It's not as Black and White as Jeff's (old) post suggests; Yes, the trend is ORMs emitting ad-hoc sql but that can have side effects too.....

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:
- dynamic sql for single objects
- SPs for parameterized lists and orders

The value of the ORM is usually its simplicity in creating the object model.  One approach is described here:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/362034/Populating-a-business-logical-layer-from-stored-pr

Comment: Link outdated for visit